# CSS transform on sass file and animations not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, css-transitions

I am trying to animate 3 divs (.line 1, .line2 and .line3) by rotating them, on click of another div (#burger).

The 3 divs are wrapped around the #burger div (these are in a .js file):

```
<div
    id="burger"
    onClick={activateResponsiveMenu}
    className={navbarStyles.burger}
  >
    <div className={navbarStyles.line1}></div>
    <div className={navbarStyles.line2}></div>
    <div className={navbarStyles.line3}></div>
  </div>
```

The CSS is written in a .scss file and imported as 'navbarStyles'.
In the CSS, I animate the divs by adding a class 'clicked' to the #burger div. As for the animations, I would like .line1 and .line3 divs to rotate and .line 2 to disappear:

```
.clicked .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg translate(-5px, 6px));
}

.clicked .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.clicked .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg translate(-5px, -6px));
}
```

The JS function that toggles the class .clicked on #burger is the following:

```
const activateResponsiveMenu = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector("#burger")
    burger.classList.toggle(navbarStyles.clicked)
}
```

The problem is that, although .line2 div's opacity is turned to 0 on click of #burger, the CSS transforms are not working and .line1 and .line3 are not rotating. All other styles are being applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acording to the transform specs the values should be space separated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform which makes your syntax invalid, you should use the following format instead

```
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This makes the divs rotate but doesn't give any transition between the first moment and when #burger is clicked, which was also my intention. I thought that would happen as well.

Comment: @franciscofcosta Firstly, you never mention transition in the question, and second you have not even used a css transition property anywhere in your code. It won't happen on its own